# Multinomial regression with duplicated data points: aggregation or mixed effects?

Tags: mixed-model, multinomial-logit, nnet, duplicate-records

I would like to run a **multinomial model**, and I would like feedback on how to deal with **duplicates**.

Suppose the following example, which is quite close to my actual research question. I have data on a the presence of plants across plots. Each plot may be occupied or not by plants with a given life form: forb, grass, shrub, tree. I would like to know how the relative proportion of each type of plant changes in response to climate and landscape. My first instinct would be the multinomial model, since the response variable (type of plant) has more than two categories (I have made a few tries with the nnet package in another context).

However, a given plot can be occupied by more than one plant, and I'm unsure about how to take this into account. For instance, in the model syntax of nnet package, a plot with 3 plants (one grass and two shrubs) would be repeated three times in the response variable.

I can think of to ways to take this into account, but I don't know how to implement them:

1. Calculate an aggregated response for each plot, similarly to
   binomial models (success vs failures, but extended to more than 2
   categories): cbind(forb, grass, shrub, tree)
2. Use plot as a random effect.

Comment: Does every plot have multiple plants?

Comment: To be more specific, my data is on non-native plants. So I have plots without non-native plants, and plots with invaded plants, with the number of plants per plot in the range 1-10 (approx).

Comment: How about a count model for each type of plant?

Comment: I'm interested in the proportion of each type of plant, and how this poportion changes in response to landscape and climate. So I think multiple count models are not suitable. I'll be more explicit in my original post.